# Call functions C++

Tags: c++, string, function, call

I want to call C++ functions on this way:

I have an array that matches strings with corresponding c++ function

```
int x() {
return 6;
}

int y(int t){

return t;
}

A functions[] = { { "x" , void*&x } , { "y", void*&y}};
```

A is as simple struct.
The program gets a string as input of user.

If i have a black-magic box  function Z , that takes as parameter a string, and searchs in array "functions" and returns the second element of struct which equals with the string parameter.
For example `Z("x")` returns  `void*&x`  ..etc..

If i don't know all the functions in functions array how can i call the returned function of Z?

for example i want something like this:

```
void *  g = Z("y");   //returns the y function
g(8);
```

I don't want a specific cast  or if/else, because for the first the first time the user maybe give "x" and the seconde time give "y", and for the second I don't want if/else cases because the number of function may be infinity.

Comment: Will all the functions have the same signature (the same type of return value and input parameters)?

Comment: As in the example I mentioned x and y functions have different signature. So the answer is no.

Comment: How do you retrieve the arguments that you will use to call the function (e.g. the `8` in your example)?

Comment: I don't know, for this reason  I asked the question. 
if there is a way that passes the parameters to the second element for each element of the table .. something like this : { "y" , void*&y(int)}

Comment: @LeAdErQ You asked how to *call* the functions, but you have to retrieve the arguments somewhere... Like where does the `8` come from? Maybe you should expand on the original problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Well, if you say that to Holt, then *I* will tell you, we don't really owe you an answer, and it's up to *you* to present it clearly. Nobody is going to trip over themselves helping someone rude.

Comment: @StoryTeller 
the requested information does not help solve the problem. The problem is specific.

Comment: You have no idea what may help solve the problem. If you did, you wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: These belong to the category "philosophies". Have a nice day.

Comment: I don't need philosophy to judge a bad question and a terrible attitude. There's an objective standard for those

Comment: It is different to ask something that I do not specify in the question, than to ask why I want it

Comment: Look into how to write a parser. Looking up terms like tokenizing,  lexing and abstract syntax tree will also be helpful.

Comment: I have read all this. If it is impossible that just you can tell me.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718187/2610810). You *will* need to know which parameter types apply to which entry in the map

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store functions with different signatures in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715219/store-functions-with-different-signatures-in-a-map)

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the functions array

```
A functions[] = { { "x" , void*&x } , { "y", void*&y}};
```

It looks to me like each function gets stored along with their name. In order to find the function with a given name, it's as simple as finding the `A` instance that stores that name. You can do this using a `for` loop to iterate over the functions array.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(functions) / sizeof(A); i++) {
    if(functions[i].name == desiredFunctionName) {
        return functions[i].fxn;
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is not how to return the correct function! But how to call this function!

Comment: Oh. That's impossible if you don't know the function's signature. @LeAdErQ

Answer (score 0):

Create a map where key value is a string e.g.- "x", "Y" and value is Function Pointer. 
When you will search with key value in map then you will get function pointer to desired function. 
Assign it to void *  g and then dereference it to call that function.