# Map of lambdas with different signatures?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm hoping to build a std::map of lambdas with varying signatures. E.g., this works:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<bool(double)>> map;

map.emplace("gt_zero", [](double a) { return a > 0; });
map.emplace("lt_zero", [](double a) { return a < 0; });

bool foo = map["gt_zero"](42); // returns true
bool bar = map["lt_zero"](42); // returns false
```

Below demonstrates what I'd also like to do in the same map, but it won't compile because the lambda signature doesn't match the map's:

```
map.emplace("equal", [](double a, double b) { return a == b; });
bool baz = map["equal"](42, 42);
```

Is there a way to define a std::map to accept lamdbas with different signatures?

EDIT: The above does not approximate my use case. It's for identifying my coding issue. The actual use case has knowledge of the signature.

EDIT: Thanks to the posters that pointed out the similar question [Store functions with different signatures in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715219/store-functions-with-different-signatures-in-a-map). Unfortunately, the code posted in that answer does not compile for VS2017/C++17.

Comment: That seems pretty dangerous. At the call site, how are you going to differentiate the different arities? You could "partially" apply a lambda so it only takes 1 argument, then put that in the map; *if* you know ahead of time what you'll want to check the equality against.

Comment: Why do you need to use the same map for both?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715219/store-functions-with-different-signatures-in-a-map

Comment: You could map to a union or `std::variant`. But you'll need to select the particular function type at the calling location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store functions with different signatures in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715219/store-functions-with-different-signatures-in-a-map)

Comment: You could store function pointers in the map... But why? edit: oh wait, that;s what the previous comment said.

Comment: The answer you linked compiles fine for me in VS2017  15.7.2 (cl  19.14.26429.4) maybe update your version