# C++ need a container to store user defined function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am trying to create a interface between user defined function and data. Let's say I need to create a function called `MapFun()`, input of `MapFun()` includes user defined function (UDF) handle and UDF inputs.

```
void userFun1(Data data, int in1, int in2){
    // user defined function 1;
}

void userFun2(Data data, int in1, int in2, std::string s){
    // user defined function 2;
}

// ...
// apply user function 1 on data
MapFun(@userFun1, data, 3, 4);
// apply user function 2 on data
MapFun(@userFun2, data, 1, 2, "algorithm");
```

User will write `userFun` and apply it with `MapFun()`. So, how to design `MapFun()`? User function may have different inputs and the signature can't be predicted. In addition, `MapFun()` won't evaluate `userFun` immediately, instead, it stores all `userFun` and do a lazy evaluation.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can't predict the signature of `userFun`, how will you know what parameters to give it?

Comment: Unfortunately, `userFun` will be defined by users. `MapFun` can't know what parameters will be used for `userFun`. I searched, and feel it might be similar to the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715219/store-functions-with-different-signatures-in-a-map/45718187

Comment: Do the user functions all have the same return type (possibly `void`)?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I misread your code snippet and was a bit confused. It sounds like you want [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).

Comment: @aschepler I think I can assume all user functions have void return type.

Comment: necessarily C++11 or also C++14/C++17?

Comment: @DanielH I checked `std::invoke` a little bit, it sounds like it is used to invoke a defined function. The problem here is I write `MapFun` but user write `userFun`, and `MapFun` does not know what `userFun` looks like. Is it possible to write a code compatible to all kinds of `userFun`?

Comment: @max66 can be any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> User function may have different inputs and the signature can't be predicted.

It seems a typical works for variadic templates

> In addition, `MapFun()` won't evaluate `userFun` immediately, instead, it stores all `userFun` and do a lazy evaluation.

Not sure to understand but I suppose you can obtain what do you want using `std::bind()` or, maybe better, with lambda functions.

I propose the following C++14 variadic template `MapFun()` function that return a lambda function that capture both user-function and argument. That function can be executed later.

```
template <typename F, typename ... Args>
auto MapFun (F const & f, Args const & ... args)
 { return [=]{ f(args...); }; }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F, typename ... Args>
auto MapFun (F const & f, Args const & ... args)
 { return [=]{ f(args...); }; }

void userFun1 (int i1, int i2)
 { std::cout << "uf1, " << i1 << ", " << i2 << std::endl; }

void userFun2 (int i1, int i2, std::string const & s)
 { std::cout << "uf2, " << i1 << ", " << i2 << ", " << s << std::endl; }

int main ()
 {
   auto l1 = MapFun(userFun1, 1, 2);
   auto l2 = MapFun(userFun2, 3, 4, "five");

   l2();
   l1();
 }
```

Comment: Capture by reference is dangerous here.  Even the example `MapFun(userFun1, 1, 2)` is likely to blow up, because the lambda object contains references to `const int&` values from temporaries initialized to `1` and `2`, and those referenced objects no longer exist when the functions are called.

Comment: @aschepler - yes, it's a incredibly stupid mistake; corrected; thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It seems that this and @aschepler 's suggestion are what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you just want to store a function and a set of arguments so that they can be called later.  This is exactly what [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) does (anyway, the simplest thing it does).  In fact, you could possibly just use `std::bind` directly in place of your `MapFun`:

```
auto func1 = std::bind(userFun1, data, 3, 4);
auto func2 = std::bind(userFun2, data, 1, 2, "algorithm");
// ... and later,
func1();
func2();
```

Note the `auto` in those: you can't (portably) write the type of any object returned by `std::bind`, and those two example objects will have different types.  But both of those would implicitly convert to the common type `std::function<void()>`.  You can store a bunch of `std::function<void()>` objects in nearly any container type you want, to be used later:

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::function<void()>> func_map;
func_map[0] = std::bind(userFun1, data, 3, 4);
func_map[1] = std::bind(userFun2, data, 1, 2, "algorithm");
// ...
auto func_iter = func_map.find(key);
if (func_iter != func_map.end() && func_iter->second) {
    (func_iter->second)();
}
```

Of course, if you want to use your name of the function, and/or if you need the explicit common return type to work well with other templates or something, you can just wrap `std::bind`:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
std::function<void()> MapFun(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::bind<void>(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Or if your `MapFun` is supposed to store the callable object inside some class member container or something, not just create and return one (it's not clear), it can of course do that by using `std::bind` and then adding the result to whatever container you need.

Comment: Thank you! I think the variadic std::bind one is what I am looking for. I guess `MapFun` does not know the signature of `f` right? Let me try some tests, those packed parameters are complicated to me...

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to backport `std::invoke` from C++17, well, its simplest form is quite straight`forward`:

```
template<class F, class... Args> decltype(auto) invoke(F &&f, Args &&...args) {
    return ::std::forward<F>(f)(::std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you suggest me write `MapFun()` to store user function, and invoke it as you suggested? 
`template<typename... ConstrT>
    void MapFun(std::function<void, Args...> f, ConstrT&&... args){
    // store f    
}`. Would that idea work?

Comment: Not as you type it. By `Args...`, do you mean `ConstrT...`? Where are you planning to store it? Besides your question's title, there is no indication that you are planning to store `f` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry `Args...` is different to `ConstrT`. I wrote it wrong. `Args...` are inputs for `f`. `args` are other inputs for `MapFun`, and it probably includes `Args...`.
`f` is defined by user, and its signature is not predictable. So if I use `std::invoke`, can I invoke a function with signature unknown?

Comment: Yes, as long as it can be invoked with that set of arguments.