# In C++, how can I create a heterogenous vector containing variafic templated objects?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, variadic-templates, factory

Hi StackOverflow Community !

I was playing at work with variadic templates, inheritance and an abstract factory pattern and am now struggling to make it work together. It seems I have reach the farthest of what I currently know about these subjects, so if you can point me a hint or a code example, you would get my entire gratitude ! Thanks in advance ;)

Here is the context (my apologies ! there is a few lines of code...):

I have a *Base* class

```cpp
template<typename... Params>
class P
{
    public:
        virtual void compute(Params&... ps) = 0;
        // other things ...

};
```

and *Derived* classes

```cpp
template<typename... Params>
class AP : public P<Params...>
{
    public:
        void compute(Params&... ps) override { _compute(std::forward<Params&>(ps)...); }
    private:
        void _compute(std::string& str) {std::cout << "AP::compute str " << str << std::endl;}
};
using A = AP<std::string>;

template<typename... Params>
class BP : public P<Params...>
{
    public:
        void compute(Params&... ps) override { _compute(std::forward<Params&>(ps)...); }
    private:
        void _compute(int& i) {std::cout << "BP::compute i " << i << std::endl;}
};
using B = BP<int>;
```

Up to here, no problems !
If I make a small `main()`, this works without any problem :

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<P<int>> p1 = std::make_unique<B>();
    int i = 15;
    p1->compute(i);

    std::unique_ptr<P<std::string>> p2 = std::make_unique<A>();
    std::string str = "abc";
    p2->compute(str);
}
```

However, we can add some more : the *Base* classes for the factory.
(These will be used with other classes than my class **P**... if you were wondering why :) )

```cpp
template<typename Base>
class Creator
{
    public:
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> create() = 0;
};

template<class Key, class T>
class Factory
{
    public:
        void store(Key key, std::unique_ptr<Creator<T>>&& creator)
        {
            _crs[key] = std::move(creator);
        }

        std::unique_ptr<T> create(Key key)
        {
            return _crs[key]->create();
        }

    private:
        std::map<Key, std::unique_ptr<Creator<T>>> _crs;
};
```

and their implementations to be able to build **P**-related objects :

```cpp
template<typename Derived, typename... Params>
class PCreator : public Creator<P<Params...>>
{
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<P<Params...>> create() override
        {
            return std::make_unique<Derived>();
        }
};

template<typename... Params>
class PFactory : public Factory<std::string, P<Params...>>
{
    public:
        PFactory()
        {
            this->store("int", std::make_unique<PCreator<BP<int>>>);
            this->store("string", std::make_unique<PCreator<AP<std::string>>>);
        }
        // create() and store() methods inherited
};
```

If I instantiate **PFactory**, compiler can obviously not do its job, because it wants template arguments for **PFactory** which would forward them to `Factory<std::string, P<Params...>>`.

But than, my factory would only be able to create one single "type" of **P** object, the one that can use these `Params`.
This is how far I went alone (and sadly no one of my colleagues has the abilities to help me...)

My goal is to be able to write something like this :

```cpp
class Thing
{
    const std::array<std::string, 2> a = {"one", "two"};
    public:
        Thing()
        {
            PFactory f;
            for(const auto& e : a)
                _ps[e] = std::move(f.create(e));
        }

        void compute()
        {
            int i = 100;
            std::string str = "qwerty";
            // additional computations...
            _ps["one"]->compute(i);
            // additional computations...
            _ps["two"]->compute(str);
        }

    private:
        std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<P>> _ps;
};
```

Here is the PoC I tried to work and rework on [CompilerExplorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5BdNDf) and from where comes the sources above.

Any help will be hugely appreciate !

---

**[Edit]** Yes, I was delusional to think I could trick the compiler to create various method signatures with runtime infos.

Solutions' sum-up :

> (@walnut: thanks!) let compute take std::any or something like that

I do not know `std::any` very well, but after rtfm-ing [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any), it could do the job, accepting the fact, that I need to cast back the parameter to what I need it to be in my Derived classes (and deal with the exception).
Sadly, on the real project, `compute()` can take more than one parameter (the reason I played with variadic templates... I did not want to care about the number or the types of the parameters in each `compute` method in each Derived class), so it would force me to create `compute(const std::any&)`  and `compute(const std::any&, const std::any&)`, etc.

> (@MaxLanghof: thanks!) One (ugly) solution is to provide all possible compute overloads as virtual functions by hand.

Yes, your right, I find it odd too (I would not go as far as «ugly», but I have no prettier solution yet, so...), but it is working.
The drawback in here is that I won't be able to store the class **P** (and related classes) in its own library as I wanted at the beginning to separate concerns («MainProgram» playing with **P**s deriving from lib::**P**).

> (@MaxLanghof: thanks!) to do the entire _ps mapping at compile-time.

I have not enough experience and knowledge in C++ yet to achieve such a thing. I need to work on that and if someone has specific links (I mean : not the first link on Google ;) ) or examples, I would be glad to learn.

Thanks for your answer so far !

---

**[Edit]** Hi ! Sorry for the delay, I just got back on this project and thank you a lot for your ideas and experience ! It means a lot !

I worked a bit with @Caleth 's and with @KonstantinStupnik 's work (really thank you for your examples : they helped me a lot to understand what I was doing !) and arrived to this point with my test case : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/AJ8Lsm where I hit a `std::bad_any_cast` exception, but don't understand why...

I suspect an issue with the pass-by-reference or the way I use a lambda to save the `compute` method in the `std::any`, but cannot be sure.
I tried to expand the types received in the `AnyCallable<void>::operator()` to find a difference with the stored function in **P**'s constructor, but seems the same to me.

I tried to pass `&AP::compute` to **P**'s constructor, but then the compiler cannot deduce the parameter types anymore...

Thank you all for your time, your help and your advice !

Comment: I am not sure what the point of all of this is, but fundamentally: `_ps["one"]` and `_ps["two"]` have the same static type. So either `compute` must be a template that accepts different types, in which case it cannot be `virtual` or it must be overloaded for the different types that it accepts in the base class. Currently `compute` is a single non-overloaded function in your base class. That cannot work.

Comment: The only way to make it work this way that I see is to let `compute` take `std::any` or something like that, but then still the caller must know the derived type of the objects in `_ps` apriori in order to not provide the wrong argument type, in which case using a container with a base class pointer is pointless.

Comment: The compiler needs to know the type of `(*_ps["..."])` at compile-time. Since that type is decided at compile-time, it cannot depend on a run-time value. You want that type to have `compute(i)` and `compute(str)` methods. But you cannot have member functions that are `virtual` and templated. One (ugly) solution is to provide all possible `compute` overloads as virtual functions by hand. What behavior do you expect for `_ps["one"]->compute(str);`?

Comment: Another possible solution is to do the entire `_ps` mapping at compile-time. But then you cannot (easily) use run-time string values instead of e.g. `"one"`. In general, type erasure requires that either a) the entire interface is part of the (non-templated) base class, or b) the caller/user code knows what type they need to retrieve. You currently fulfill neither, and you'll have to choose one of these options if you want a heterogeneous container.

Comment: `template<typename... Params>
class AP` isn't really working, only `AP<std::string>` would work.

Comment: @MaxLanghof ["b) the caller/user code knows what type they need to retrieve"] how could I reflect your sentence in my sources ? I am not sure to understand that well (apologies! and thanks for your answers!)

Comment: @Psyko Consider [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). It performs universal type erasure. You can store anything in it, but you consequently have no action that you could perform on the type-erased value (other than destruction I guess). But that doesn't mean it's useless, because you can retrieve the stored object as long as you (the user/caller) know what type is in there _at compile time_, by using [`std::any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast). You could use this to store objects of different types in a heterogeneous container. But unless..

Comment: ...a user of that container knows which elements would have which types (at compile time), you cannot do anything meaningful with the elements. [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is another example. To properly use type erasure in your code, the `P` would have to be a non-templated base class and the derived classes would have to be the templated. Then you could have e.g. a `template<class...Ts> computeWith(P&, Ts&&...ts)` that casts from the base (`P`) to the templated version and then calls its `compute` accordingly. That'll work but might be inconvenient.

Comment: For an example with `std::any`, have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718187/2610810)

Comment: quick and dirty prototype: https://psty.io/p?q=18f8a

Comment: You need to exactly match the argument types. `bad_any_cast` means you didn't. [See fixed](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v3-atp) You need `const std::string &` in main, and `int &, const std::string &` in AP::compute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type-erase the parameters, so long as you can specify them at the call site.

Minimally:

```
#include <functional>
#include <any>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Ret>
struct AnyCallable
{
    AnyCallable() {}
    template<typename F>
    AnyCallable(F&& fun) : AnyCallable(std::function(fun)) {}
    template<typename ... Args>
    AnyCallable(std::function<Ret(Args...)> fun) : m_any(fun) {}
    template<typename ... Args>
    Ret operator()(Args&& ... args) 
    { 
        return std::invoke(std::any_cast<std::function<Ret(Args...)>>(m_any), std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    }
    template<typename ... Args>
    Ret compute(Args ... args) 
    { 
        return operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    }
    std::any m_any;
};

template<>
struct AnyCallable<void>
{
    AnyCallable() {}
    template<typename F>
    AnyCallable(F&& fun) : AnyCallable(std::function(fun)) {}
    template<typename ... Args>
    AnyCallable(std::function<void(Args...)> fun) : m_any(fun) {}
    template<typename ... Args>
    void operator()(Args&& ... args) 
    { 
        std::invoke(std::any_cast<std::function<void(Args...)>>(m_any), std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    }
    template<typename ... Args>
    void compute(Args ... args) 
    { 
        operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    }
    std::any m_any;
};

using P = AnyCallable<void>;

void A(std::string& str) {std::cout << "AP::compute i " << str << std::endl;}
void B(int i) {std::cout << "BP::compute i " << i << std::endl;}

class Thing
{
    public:
        Thing(){}

        void compute()
        {
            int i = 100;
            std::string str = "qwerty";
            // additional computations...
            ps["one"].compute<int>(i);
            // additional computations...
            ps["two"].compute<std::string&>(str);
        }

    private:
        std::map<std::string, P> ps = { { "one", B }, { "two", A } };
};
```

[Or with all the Factory](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bafec27e8ed7451)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Caleth ! Your example made me understand a lot of things so far. I used your work to try to better mine which lead to the second edit of my post (sadly). Thanks again for your help !