# How to call a generic std::function with a list of void* parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I have a std::map where I store some arbitrary methods that I want to call later.

```
map<string, function<void(void)>> methods;

template<typename R, typename ...P>
void storeMethod(const string& name, const function<R(P...)>& method) {
    methods[name] = method;
}
```

A the time of calling, I get the parameters to call the method with in a `vector<void*>`, where the first element is a pointer where I will store the return value.
How do I automatically cast these parameters to the corresponding types of the method I want to call?
Should I store the types in some way maybe?

```
void callMethod(const string& name, vector<void*> parameters) {
    auto method = methods[name];
    // How to call 'method' with all the parameters casted to the required types?
}
```

For example, if I orignally called `storeMethod()` with a `function<int(string a, float b)>`, I need a generic way to call it in `callMethod()` like this:

```
*((int*)parameters[0]) = method(*((string*)parameters[1]), *((float*)parameters[2]));
```

Comment: why do you get a parameters as `vector<void*>` ? Using `void*` is sometimes needed when C is involved, but a `vector<void*>` is not something you ever need

Comment: `std::function<void(void)>` can store a function (and wrap it with type-erasure) that does not take any arguments and does not return anything. You cannot store inside a function that accepts arguments or returns.

Comment: In C++, you should use templates and parameters pack instead of this weird `std::vector<void*>` to forward parameters in a generic way.

Comment: _"If I orignally called `storeMethod()` with a `function<int(string a, float b)>`..."_ — That's not possible: https://godbolt.org/z/-y33BA.

Comment: @DanielLangr isnt there some specialization of `std::function` that can store functions of any signature? I remember something like that but cannot find it anymore

Comment: @idclev463035818 there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715219/store-functions-with-different-signatures-in-a-map/45718187#45718187), but it's horrible

Comment: @idclev463035818 Don't know about specialization, but there is `std::any`.

Comment: @Caleth then I remember wrong. I am not a fan of `std::function` anyhow. Imho it is too often over- and misused. It looks tempting, but actually often it isnt really needed

Comment: please provide a bit more context. How do you store methods in the map? What functions to you want to store?  How do you call them? Why are the parameters coming as a `vector<void*>`? Type safety is a good thing, its nothing you should give up for "convenience"

Comment: I would simply say that if you want the functionality described in the question, then C++ is definitely not the right programming language for this task.

Comment: - Parameters come as `void*` because I'm dealing with a C library
- @Fa

Comment: "void* because I'm dealing with a C library" ... ok but a `vector<void*>` cannot come from a c library. How do you know what is the actual type?

Comment: I used `vector` just to simplify things, in reality is C struct with a C array and its size and some other stuff

Comment: Is the set of possible types that come from that C library limited to some predefined subset?

Comment: @Fareanor can you give me more info about this?

Comment: @DanielLangr no, it's a scripting library so functions should work with any type

Comment: If I correctly understand the parameters are generated at runtime as user input. In that case you can't use templates.

Comment: @ThomasSablik in fact I was thinking about a solution based on storing the required types along with the function, then "iterate" them at the time of calling, Do you think it is possible in c++?

Comment: @DanielLangr it can be done in c++, it is a bit hacky and I wouldn't use it in production, but it is fun ;)

Comment: @debevv Take a look at the `OpaqueFunctionImpl` from the [Caleth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62445932/11455384), this is what I meant by the use of templates parameter pack. You can find the information you requested about it in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to wrap `method` in something that can remember the parameter types.

```
struct OpaqueFunction {
    virtual std::any call(const std::vector<std::any> &) = 0;
};

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct OpaqueFunctionImpl : OpaqueFunction {
    OpaqueFunctionImpl(std::function<R(Args...)> f) : f(std::move(f)) {}

    std::any call(const std::vector<std::any> & parameters) override {
        return call_impl(parameters, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    }
private:
    template <size_t... I>
    std::any call_impl(const std::vector<std::any> & parameters, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return f(std::any_cast<Args>(parameters.at(I))...);
    }
    std::function<R(Args...)> f;
};

class Methods {
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<OpaqueFunction>> methods;
public:
    template<typename R, typename ... Args>
    void storeMethod(std::string name, std::function<R(Args...)> method) {
        methods[std::move(name)] = std::make_unique<OpaqueFunctionImpl<R, Args...>>(std::move(method));
    }

    template<typename R>
    R callMethod(const std::string & name, const std::vector<std::any> & parameters) {
        return std::any_cast<R>(methods.at(name)->call(parameters));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Callable` type to functions that take different types of arguments and then, store that in a `vector` (using vector here for simplicity):

```
struct Callable {
    Callable(std::function<void()> f) : zero_(std::move(f)) {}
    Callable(std::function<void(int)> f) : one_(std::move(f)) {}

    void operator()() { zero_(); }
    void operator()(int x) { one_(x); }

    std::function<void()> zero_;
    std::function<void(int)> one_;
};

//vector of methods
std::vector<Callable> methods;
```

To store a method, you can either use a `template`-ized function or just use overloads. I am using overloads here:

```
void addMethod(std::function<void()> func)
{
    methods.push_back(Callable(func));
}

void addMethod(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    methods.push_back(Callable(func));
}
```

And then to finally call a function:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void callMethod(int idx, Args ...args) {
    auto method = methods[idx];

    method(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    addMethod([](int x){
        std::cout << "I am function(int)" << x << '\n';
    });

    addMethod([](){
        std::cout << "I am just function()\n";
    });


    callMethod(0, 200);
    callMethod(1);
}
```

This is the simplest possible way I can think of to achieve this. Their might be better ways and I am really curious about them.

Try it out here: https://godbolt.org/z/HS5a7p

Comment: you would need a member for each possible function signature

Comment: That is true I am afraid.

Comment: And, this does not solve the problem how to retrieve arguments from that `vector<void*>`.

Comment: Interesting, but parameters will be passed to callMethod() in a list/vector of void*. How should i adapt this?