# Map of template functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, typedef, stdmap

I want to make a `std::map` with `std::string` keys that contains functions.
These functions should be `templates` in order to work with different numeric values:

```
template <typename T> T (*pfunc)(T,T);
```

The map declarations looks like this:

```
std::map<std::string, pfunc> funcMap;
```

I know I need a *template argument list* for `pfunc` but I don't really know how to do it.

[EDIT]

Taking in count the comments. I would like to be able to:
Create a function template as:

```
template <typename T> 
T myMax(T x, T y) 
{ 
   return (x > y)? x: y; 
}
```

or

```
template <typename T> 
T myMin(T x, T y) 
{ 
   return (x < y)? x: y; 
}
```

- Then add it to my map: `funcMap["myMax"] = myMax;` or `funcMap["myMin"] = myMin;`
- And use it as:

```
funcMap["myMax"]<int>(3,4);
funcMap["myMax"]<float>(3.1,4.5);
funcMap["myMin"]<int>(3,4);
funcMap["myMin"]<float>(3.1,4.5);
```

- Is this posible? any better ideas?

Comment: Are you wanting one map with e.g. `pfunc<int>` and `pfunc<double>` mixed, or multiple maps?

Comment: A template is only a type once it's instatiated. You can't have a map that holds a template. It need to be a `std::map<std::string, pfunc<int>> funcMap;` or similar.

Comment: The more relevant question here is how you are planning to use this. It's hard to point you in the right direction without seeing the use-case. I'm guessing you are planning to feed run-time string values into your map. You should provide more information as a [mcve].

Comment: @Caleth I would like my map to be able to use any numeric values, and just choosing a type when calling the function inside the map

Comment: Are you wanting to "put function templates in `funcMap`", or out functions of different signatures? The latter is [both hard to implement and hard to use correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715219/store-functions-with-different-signatures-in-a-map/45718187#45718187)

Comment: I.e. do you want something like `funcMap = { { "sine", std::sin }, { "sqrt", std::sqrt }, ... }` or `funcMap = { { "int_func", [](int a, int b){ return a + b;} }, { "double_func", [](double a, double b){ return a + b;} }, ... }`?

Comment: @Caleth I want to put functions of different signatures AND I want to use templates (or something similar) so that the type is defined after the map declaration.  I'm taking a look to the link you sent, it's similar to what I want, but I don't want to signatures with fixes types , thanks for you interest!

Comment: Put in examples of calling these functions that you want. I really *don't* advise `AnyCallable`. You might be able to get away with having `funcMap` be a variable template: `template <typename T> std::map<std::string, pfunc<T>> funcMap = { ... };` You would then call it like `int res = funcMap<int>["some_func"](1, 2);`

Comment: Note that: 1) When you call a function, the type of its arguments and its return type must be resolved at compile time. 2) Templates do not exist on runtime. They must be instantiated and you can work only with these instances. 3) There is nothing as a pointer to a function template. You can have a pointer to a function (which may happen to be a function template instance).

Comment: @Caleth I added to the question the way I want to call the function

Comment: @Caleth when I do `template <typename T>
std::map<std::string, pfunc<T>> funcMap;` I get the error `Template argument for template type parameter must be a type`

Comment: All the elements of a map must have the same type. A function template is not a function, does not have a type, and can't be stored anywhere. You can't instantiate a template at rutime. I think you should take a step back and think some more about your ultimate problem - whatever that is - instead of being stuck on this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [best you will get](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48d1dcadfbfaec1f) is

```
template <typename T> 
T myMax(T x, T y) 
{ 
   return (x > y)? x: y; 
} 

template <typename T> 
T myMin(T x, T y) 
{ 
   return (x < y)? x: y; 
} 

template <typename T> using pfunc = T(*)(T, T);

template <typename T> std::map<std::string, pfunc<T>> funcMap = { 
    { "myMax", myMax }, 
    { "myMin", myMin } 
};
```

You will need to define all your function templates before defining funcMap, or limit yourself to a pre-determined set of types. I don't know of a way of populating infinite `funcMap` instantiations with infinite function template instantiations after it's definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic lambda:

```
[](auto x, auto y) { return myMax(x, y); }
```

However, this is not a function pointer, but rather an object.

Answer (score 1):

As we don't know much about your final goal, we can't say if there is an easy workaround to your problem. When you are in front of a kind of unsolvable problem, you can follow the pragmatic programmer principle called "Cutting the Gordian Knot" by asking yourself:

- Is there an easier way?
- Am I solving the right problem?
- Why is this a problem?
- What makes it hard?
- Do I have to do it this way?
- Does it have to be done at all?

That's said, I think Caleth solution is the most straightforward. If you want a solution with a single map containing the whole overload set, here is a proof of concept (**WARNING**: It has many flaws and works only in your case).

First, you need some helpers to detect if a class has the right function call operator overload or not:

```
namespace helpers {
    // simplify is_detected pattern (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)
    template <typename Dummy, template <typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
    struct is_detected : std::false_type {};

    template <template <typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
    struct is_detected<std::void_t<Op<Args...>>, Op, Args...> : std::true_type {};

    template <template <typename...> typename Op, typename... Args>
    constexpr bool is_detected_v = is_detected<void, Op, Args...>::value;

    // Check if a class has an overloaded function call operator with some params
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    using has_fcall_t = decltype(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Args>()...));

    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    constexpr bool has_fcall_v = is_detected_v<has_fcall_t, T, Args...>;
}
```

Then, you define your basic numerical operations:

```
template <typename T>
struct Additionner {
    T operator()(T a, T b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Multiplier{
    T operator()(T a, T b) {
        return a * b;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Incrementor {
    T operator()(T a) {
        return a++;
    }
};
```

The next step is to gather all the specialization of an operation you are interested in in a single class:

```
// Used to store many overloads for the same operations
template <typename... Bases>
struct NumOverloader : Bases...
{
    using Bases::operator()...;
};
```

Internally, we use a [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to simulate a kind of heterogeneous map. We wrap it into a class to provide a straightforward interface to use:

```
// wrapper around a variant that expose a universal function call operator
template <typename... Ts>
class NumDispatcher {
public:
    NumDispatcher() = default;

    template <typename T> // Fine tuning needed (see https://mpark.github.io/programming/2014/06/07/beware-of-perfect-forwarding-constructors/)
    NumDispatcher(T&& t) : m_impl(std::forward<T>(t)){
    }

    // visit the variant
    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args) {
        using type = std::common_type_t<Args...>;
        type t{};
        std::visit([&](auto&& visited) {
            using vtype = std::decay_t<decltype(visited)>;
            if constexpr(helpers::has_fcall_v<vtype, Args...>)
                t = std::forward<vtype>(visited)(args...);
            else
                throw std::runtime_error("bad op args");
        }, m_impl);
        return t;
    }
private:
    using Impl = std::variant<Ts...>;
    Impl m_impl;
};
```

The final step is to define your mapping:

```
// Here you need to know at compile-time your overloads
using MyIncrementors = NumOverloader<Incrementor<int>, Incrementor<unsigned>>;
using MyAdditionners = NumOverloader<Additionner<int>, Additionner<double>>;
using MyMultipliers = NumOverloader<Multiplier<int>, Multiplier<double>>;

using MyValueType = NumDispatcher<MyIncrementors, MyAdditionners, MyMultipliers>;
using MyMap = std::map<std::string, MyValueType>;
```

And then, you can play with it:

```
Num::MyMap m;
m["add"] = Num::MyAdditionners{};
m["mul"] = Num::MyMultipliers{};
m["inc"] = Num::MyIncrementors{};

auto d = m["add"](2.4, 3.4);
std::cout << d << std::endl;
// auto d2 = m["add"](1.3f, 2); // throw no overload match
std::cout << m["inc"](1) << std::endl;
//std::cout << m["inc"](1,1) << std::endl; // throw no overload match
std::cout << m["mul"](3, 2) << std::endl;
```

[DEMO HERE](https://godbolt.org/z/fadqnj).

Regards.